# Android in-app with remote server:how to get verified list of all purchases

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I'm implementing the in-app purchase of the files stored on my server.

The idea is to send verified list (like in **RESTORE_TRANSACTIONS** returns) to the server and It returns available items that user bought.
But the documentation says:

**"Note: You should use the RESTORE_TRANSACTIONS request type only when your application is installed for the first time on a device or when your application has been removed from a device and reinstalled."**

So I'm guessing that the constant usage of the **RESTORE_TRANSACTIONS** is a bad idea.

But there's no more requests that returns full list. Keeping purchases in the db like in Dungeons example is not secure.

Is there exist another way to get verified list of purchases or maybe **RESTORE_TRANSACTIONS** usage is appropriate?

Answer (score 1):

If you use RESTORE_TRANSACTIONS too frequently, that account might be temporarily blocked. So only use it on first run, or periodically. If you want to check for items with a server each time the app runs, use unmanaged items and have your server keep track of each user's items. 
Then you can call home as often as you want.

As for purchases in a local db not being secure, it is only an issue on rooted devices, and you can obfuscate your database to that adding/changing items is not straightforward.

Comment: Thanks Nikolay. Unmanaged items is not an option, because in that case I have to add some sort of auth, and it's not good for users.

Comment: You can actually use the Google account for authentication, just as the Android Market/Play Store does, so it wouldn't be much different from the user's point of view. It will be more work for your server-side component though. If you wan't to use managed items, just cache them in a local file/db and obfuscate them, that should pretty much cover it. If you want to make it harder still for potential crackers, you can use native code, but that is yet more work, you have to decide if it is worth your time.